# Adding UI review to QA process in mobile app development

Tags: mobile-applications

As a UI designer, I'm looking for a way to be part of the QA process and review margins, font sizes, etc. on a mobile app.

In the past, I've been able to 'view source' on a website and verify specific items, like font size, margin width, hex codes. But there is no 'view source' tool that I know of for a mobile App.

As a UX/UI designer, I don't have access to the code, to ensure that changes match layouts I've provided were correctly implemented by developers. I only have the ability to view the app on a device and trust my eyes - which can't determine accuracy to the pixel or a specific hex code.

I'm aware that every company's QA process may be unique. But I'd like feedback on how others have solved this specific piece of the process.

Comment: If you _as the designer_ can't see any issues with the current UI, it seems quite unlikely that you'd find any priority work this way.

Comment: Apologies - not understanding your comment? There are definitely changes that could be missed at a glance, but need to be exact due to brand guidelines and other requirements. It's best to view code and verify changes are exactly as requested. Example with color: A color may look correct, but different monitors will present that color differently. It's best to see a hex code. We can't rely on our eyes alone.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually?  If there are brand requirements or something, you should have it be part of your automated testing, or even build pipeline.

Comment: Apologies for kinda stupid question but what tool have you been using to 'view source' on a website?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie Good point! I think we need to solidify a couple measurements, but we're working on implementing automations to the build pipeline right now. Thank you!

Comment: @AndriyFabirovskyy For view source, Dev tools in a browser. My experience has been with web design, where that was all I needed before. Now that we're working on mobile apps, that option isn't available to us.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be better to go to the source code and see it there. Thesource code should be in some git repository like Bitbucket, Azure Repos, and others, so it's just about setting up the right permissions for you (ask the DevOps guy/team).

For example, on Android, styles, colors, etc. might be defined in xml (something like `res/layout/*.xml`) files, e.g.

```xml
<Button
      android:id="@+id/customButton2"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_below="@id/customButton"
      android:layout_marginTop="24sp"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:text="My Custom button"/>
```

or:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  
    <!--When Button is not enabled -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#b6b7b5" />
    <!--When Button is in pressed state -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#22a540" />
    <!--When Button is in selected state -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#fabcff" />
    <!--Default Background Color -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
  
</selector>
```

That's where you can find it. Just look around in the code.

Comment: For us, we're working in Azure Repos, and working with Xamarin, XAML, XCode and Android code... so maybe that's what I'll have to do.